# How to automatically change the Incident state after "Create Normal Change" action?

Tags: servicenow

I would like to set the state to "Awaiting Change" when a Change is created from the incident using "Create Normal Change" or "Create Emergency Change" UI action.

Comment: Have you tried anything to achieve this, if so what, and how did it fail?

Comment: I tried changing the script in UI Action > Create Normal Change but it did not seem like a good practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a change from either of those *UI Actions*, the Change Request field is populated with a reference to the one that was generated.

You can create a *Business Rule* for this that triggers when this happens. You can change the **State** once the **Change Request** field *changes*.

---

**Name**: Change Created

**Table**: Incident

When to run

**Update**: checked

Filter Conditions:

- **Change Request** *changes*
- -- and -- **Change Request** *is not* **empty**

**Actions**

Set field values

- **State** *To* **On Hold**
- **On hold reason** *to* **Awaiting Change**

---

Something like this

[image]